# How do I get Drupal to 'discover' a new layout .tpl?

Tags: 7, theming

I wanted to make a slight variation of a .tpl layout a plugin uses. To do that I simply when into the plugins file structure and duplicated one of its layout folders and renamed the files within (.css, .tpl and .inc). I then made the changes to the .tpl file.

In the .inc file I find:

```
$plugin = [
  'title' => t('Two Col 50/50'),
  'category' => t('Foundation'),
  'icon' => 'icon.png',
  'theme' => 'foundation_twocol_50_50',
  'admin css' => 'foundation-twocol-50-50.css',
  'regions' => [
    'left' => t('Left'),
    'right' => t('Right'),
  ],
];
```

All I did here was alter these names slightly to:

```
   $plugin = [
      'title' => t('Two Col 70/30'),
      'category' => t('Foundation'),
      'icon' => 'icon.png',
      'theme' => 'foundation_twocol_70_30',
      'admin css' => 'foundation-twocol-70-30.css',
      'regions' => [
        'left' => t('Left'),
        'right' => t('Right'),
      ],
    ];
```

I then refreshed my cache and theme registry, but the new 70/30 option does not appear when I go to swap layout for the mini-panel I'm working on.

Is there something I must do to 'tell' drupal this new layout exists?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a Panels layout and Drupal won't discover it. You have to manually add it to the theme's .info file like this:

plugins[panels][layouts] = your_new_layout_name